# Mannerisms of a former nomadic people

Tags: magic, culture, history

Okay so I'm not so sure what to put here since this is my first time but my question is:

A group of former nomadic people (They are similar to a wolf pack in terms of their nomadic days) are looking to settle and build a city, listed below are the circumstances or the current situation the people are in

- They decided to settle down in a fertile canyon with random distributed patches of vegetation with rivers and springs.
- Located above and surrounding the canyon is a dry desert
- The area they live on the continent is relatively far from humans but close to other non-human races
- The neighboring races are either feel neutral or interested in their presence
- Some of the rivers are directly connected to the ocean forming small estuaries.
- There are about 2000-3000 people approximately.
- Most of the people were picked up as they traveled.
- They also picked up those of their kind who were exiled from their former homeland.
- They are a hunting and gathering society and recently started with agriculture.
- They do not keep livestock.
- They can shape-shift.
- The area they decided to settle in has two seasons dry and wet with the wet season taking up most of the year on where they decide to settle.
- They transform into Cryptids and often hide which is a reason why they used to be nomadic
- They are usually hunted down for fame.
- They are people who hate strife and violence
- They are quite intellectual which helps them not to be found by humans
- They have a long lifespans sometimes reaching to a thousand
- They can be forced to transform when the area they are in is quite close to the sun or to the moon.
- Though they hate violence they have powerful magic depending on their transformation.
- They dislike humans but have no qualms other races
- They are literate and keep logs of their travels often creating stories
- As with real animals, their cryptid forms have molting/shedding periods even some have heats
- The language and writing system they speak is similar to the other races
- They have a low chance of conceiving a child and are very protective of the youth and young.
- The original nomads were part of a former monarch kingdom (similar to the Europe monarchy).  The kingdom was a mix of different races (with no humans) which fell into ruin
- They have basic trade knowledge
- They are really appreciative and give meaning to physical things such as gifts given by others and the like
- A small number of the people have knowledge in construction (around 300 of them)
- They value education
- They were nomadic for 4 generations.  (including the ones they took in)
- They don't believe in any type of divine being but do not reject the idea as well.
- None of the nomads are nobles or royals from their former home.
- They sell their molting or cracked pieces of horns to certain kingdoms and nations they feel comfortable trust deeply and safe with.
- The current leader has the power to see events (I based the leader's powers by the cryptid Mothman who is known to appear in areas when disaster is going to strike)
- Other notable cryptid transformations are plesiosaurs (they are implied to be sea monsters such as the Loch Ness monster and can only transform when they are wet.)
- The Yetis (they can transform only when temperatures are cold enough and control ice)
- The Chupacabras (they transform when feeding and can manipulate their blood and other beings' blood) who often feed on other hunted animal's blood than the meat.  These are what majority of the people transform into.

How would the factors listed above influence their mannerisms (such as how they act, their values and how they raise their young) towards each other and their own people

Comment: Hello and welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! "Culture" is always a very broad term. I think that for example their exact form of shape-shifting would influence their culture a lot: What forms do they have? How painful is the transformation? Is there a time-limit? How much time does the transformation take? ... All in all I think your question is what we call "opinion-based". There is no somewhat objective way to rate answers, as we can only guess and it's mostly up to the writer of the story, which is you.

Comment: If others on this site agree with me your question might get put on hold for some time. This allows the community to help you with editing the question so that it fits the sites scope. Answers will not be allowed during this period as edits could invalidate them, which is something we don't want. After some edits of yours the question can be reopened. Is there a certain aspect of culture you want to focus on? This could help in narrowing down the question and finding references to make objective answers possible.

Comment: What is their region/continent and how far from human population do they want to settle down? Also, do they want to settle in jungle, plains or desert? Is the question about modern times or medieval times/dark ages?

Comment: I'm going to agree with "too broad." There's a LOT of GOOD questions in this one question. They probably need to be unpacked. You know what might be a good way, Savious? Try this... write up the question with what you think the culture is like and then ask if any of it seems implausible. Checking a model for inconsistencies is much more within the scope of SE than brainstorming all the variations on a model. We have some questions like that, but they tend to be narrower range for brainstorming.

Comment: Your edits provide a lot more information, which is very good. I still see one problem: questions should focus on one aspect, not a multitude of them. Each of your points in the last list provide enough content for a separate question. If you don't want to follow the advice of @SRM I would recommend deleting all points in that last list except for one. Then you can get some feedback and incorporate that into other separate questions, thereby slowly building this world. "Clothes", "self-defense" and "dealing with others" look like good starting points for a series to me. What do you think?

Comment: BTW: You can comment on your own post and @Username us if you have any questions about our comments. Once you have 20 reputation you can also go to the chat and ask there, or you could post on Meta. Just in case somethings unclear.

Comment: Just saw your edit and I now think it is a very good question fitting the site. Good job! I can't vote to reopen because I don't have the reputation. I hope some of the more experienced users reopen this question. You need 5 "reopen-votes" from people with over 3k rep. Because of your edit this question should be in the corresponding review-queue.

Comment: @Secespitus thanks for your help Inat least have an idea on what to put  and properly narrow down my questions on the site :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proverbs**

- Never speak loudly, even when angry. (Loud speech gives away the location of the speaker and can potentially fall on the ears of a wandering human)
- Solitude is virtue. (A loner is much less likely to be discovered by humans than a group)
- He who only lives in the night, lives the longest! (It is better to be active only at night, in order to avoid attracting unwanted attention of humans)
- Longest walks the foot which leaves no footprint. (Try and leave no footprints for humans to track and follow you)

**Dress Code**

They would wear dresses which resemble the color of their environment, thus making them difficult to spot for prying human eyes. The dress would probably not be too loose, so that when they transform into larger sized animals, the dress easily tears off and does not drag behind, making movement difficult. Their footwear would consist of plain-soled shoes which do not leave any footmarks. Being intelligent and belonging to hunter-gatherer background, they would probably carry one weapon with them at all times.

Considering that they are just beginning to adopt agriculture, it is highly likely that their dresses would consist of animal skins, coarsely sewn with animal fiber.

Answer (score 1):

What clothing you wear depends on the way you live in the resources available to you look for cultures who live in similar environments to your people and then use that as a Base for their clothing.

Since they don't seem that problems with other races they might settle near or Ally themselves with a friendly race for protection against humans just as the American Indians often allied with one European power to protect them from another.

Don't know not enough information to go into details about their overall ceremonies practices. Since they're hunted by humans and overall dislike them, imagine a lot of their practices would be very anti Human centered. The greatest heroes would be people that have outwitted or escape from humans ( they're non-violent so I say escaped as opposed to killed or harmed). As you said they are non-violent so their morals Ford evolve on being clever can outwit in your opponents instead of killing them.